# Why does a clever Satan fight with God even though he knows he will lose?

Tags: biblical-basis, satan, angels, philosophy

There was war in heaven (oh yes there was) and Satan lost his place in heaven when he was defeated. What biblical reason is there to show Satan's reasoning behind fighting with God (despite the fact that he knows he will lose)?

Comment: I haven't found a specific reference to this in the Bible but Satan's motivation is to make everyone miserable like himself. [2 Nephi 2:27](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/2.27?lang=eng#26); [3 Nephi 9:2](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/3-ne/9.2?lang=eng#1)

Comment: Why do clever humans fight with God even though they know they will lose? :P

Answer (score 1):

Since the **Philosophy** tag was raised. This is what I think.

Satan and the demons fear God. They are not going to fight against God. If anything Satan is out to get us. So is the antichrist who will trick us to fight against Christ Jesus.

He was cast out of Heaven. Luke 10:18 NET

> So he said to them, I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven.

Satan did not even put up a fight. Here, he was simply thrown out. Ezekiel 28:17

> Your heart became proud on account of your beauty, and you corrupted
>   your wisdom because of your splendor. So I threw you to the earth; I
>   made a spectacle of you before kings

Satan is a liar, [John 8:44 NET](http://biblehub.com/john/8-44.htm)

> for he is a liar and the father of lies

At the battle of Armageddon, Satan will hide as we will be tricked to fight Christ Jesus.

I think this is how we will be tricked:

> "There's nothing more reliable than a man whose loyalty can be bought
>   for hard cash" Boris Balkan, [The Ninth Gate](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142688/quotes)

Comment: are you serious? Read Rev 12:7 and you will see there was a war in heaven satan fought with the angels of God. Yes he fell and was cast down and yes he went down but not without a fight.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that Satan knows he will lose? The Bible says that Satan will lose in the end, but it doesn't say that he knows this. Perhaps Satan does not believe that the Bible is true on this point, and he thinks that he can win. After all, in pretty much every human war, both sides enter the war predicting that they will win. It seems unlikely that Satan would have rebelled to begin with if he knew in advance that he was doomed to lose.

Here is a totally fanciful scenario, but one that I think is plausible: In the beginning, God creates the universe and people and the angels. At some point in there he creates Satan. So he creates him and he tells him, "I just created you." But at some point Satan starts to say to himself, "How do I know that God created me? Just because he said so? Maybe I and all the other angels, AND God, evolved by random processes. Maybe we all just sprang into existence by chance, in some kind of Big Bang. God happened to be the first to evolve. Then he ran around as other angels came into existence and told them that he created them, and we all just believed him. Maybe he's no more powerful than any of us, or just a little more powerful, and if a bunch of us got together, we could overthrow him and we could be in charge."

As I say, it's total fiction that I just made up. But something LIKE that scenario would be consistent with the Bible and what we see in the world around us.

Answer (score 1):

Satan  thinks he  is  God.

Isaiah 14;14  I  will  ascend  above  the  heights  of  the  clouds;  I  will  be  like  the  most  High.
II Thessalonians  2;4  Who  opposeth  and  exhalteth  himself  above  all  that  is  called  God,  or  that  is  worshipped;  so  that  he  as  God  sitteth  in  the  temple  of  God  shewing  himself  that he  is  God.

Revelation 12;12  Therefore  rejoice,  ye  heavens,  and  ye  that  dwell  in  them.  Woe  to  the  inhabiters  of  the  earth  and  of  the  sea  for  the  devil  is  come  down  unto you  having  great  wrath,  because  he  knoweth  that  he  hath  but  a  short  time.

Ezekiel 28;18  Thou  has  defiled  thy  sanctuaries  by  the  multitude  of  thine  iniquites,  by   the  iniquity  of  thy  traffic;  therefore  will I  bring  forth  a  fire  from  the  midst  of  thee,  it  shall  devour  thee,  and  I  will  bring  thee  to  ashes  upon  the  earth  in  the  sight  of  all  them  that  behold  the.

Answer (score 0):

I write a short answer because it is quite simple.  **The Bible reveals almost nothing about the internal reasonings of devils or Satan.**  It does however described them as being 'evil' in their desire.  This in of itself answers the question for we only need to use common observation of the sinful nature to see similar behaviors in men.   For example, when a insane criminal knows he will be caught, hatred and pride will often make such a person attempt to 'take down' everybody else into their misery.  In fact it is such a common evil desire that it is a staple theme in crime & action films.

If out of pride and hate men fight against God to cause others to follow them in their doom, how much more will devils who are filled with even more rage strive for the same ends? However as reasonable as this is, it still may not point the whole unrevealed picture as the Bible does not satisfy our curiosity about demonic motivations with any clarity.  Also, we can't suppose the Devil, as clever as he is, to be wise enough to fully believe the extent of how unavoidable his doom is, or how little he can actually achieve any of his goals. It may be that part of his insanity is to, in some sense, not believe God...still. We can't assume either way so we leave it behind cursed closed curtains.

Comment: Can you find verses to back up your statements? He wants a "biblical" reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why God chose the Judas as one of Lord jesus disciple even though God knows very well about Judas that he betrayed Jesus for thirty pieces of silver and afterwards hanged himself (Matthew 26:14,16). God has good purpose for all of us Romans 8:28-30 but If we reject Him, He is not responsible. Anyway do you know Satan is doing the will of God always even Satan has some power. See Rev. 17:17.Isa. 10:15. Amen Lord.